# Stripe Prorate Daily

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe as payment gateway with proration true. Which is charging upto exact second. I need to charge prorated daily basis.
For example - All the subscription done at

1. 2018-06-25 16:47:08
2. 2018-06-25 11:22:15
3. 2018-06-25 13:33:59

should be treated as-

1. 2018-06-25 00:00:00

Below is my code-

```
Map<String, Object> subscriptionParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
subscriptionParams.put("customer", customerId);
subscriptionParams.put("items", items);
subscriptionParams.put("billing_cycle_anchor", 1st of next month);
Subscription.create(subscriptionParams);
```

Alternatively- can we change proration time from exact seconds to hour or day. ie. all the subscription done in same hour or day will charge equally.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a flag you can set to define proration behavior on Subscription creation, but Stripe offers an optional parameter, that upon updating a subscription, you can pass it to impact how a subscription is prorated, `proration_date` --- if you wanted to prorate all changes on 2018-06-25 from the start of the day:

```
updateParams.put("proration_date", 1529884800);
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription-proration_date

Comment: let say subscription created on 2018-06-25 16:47:08,when attempted to update 2018-06-25 00:00:00 using `proration_date` this throws exception says given time is outside range,& also this updation will apply on updated quantity only.